# Regex to match a 2-digit number (to validate Credit/Debit Card Issue number)

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I would like to use regex to match a string of exactly 2 characters, and both of those characters have to be between 0 and 9. The string to match against would be coming from a single-line text input field when an ASP.NET MVC view is rendered

So far, I have the regex

```
[0-9]{2}
```

and from the following list of example string inputs

- 456
- 55 44
- 12

the following matches are returned when I apply the regex

- 45
- 55
  44
- 12

So, I have kind of half the solution....what I actually want to enforce is that the string is also exactly 2 characters long, so that from the list of strings, the only one that should be matched is

```
12
```

I am an admitted amateur at regular expressions and am just using this to validate a card issue number on an ASP.NET MVC model as below....

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("[0-9]{2}")]
public string IssueNumber { get; set; }
```

I'm sure that what i'm asking is quite simple but I wasn't able to find any examples that limited the length as part of the matching .

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: If you are new to regular expressions, you may want to try the Expresso tool ... http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Comment: Do you have a `List<String>` or is it a String like `45\n32\n69`? That would have impact on single- /multiline mode operations.

Comment: @dognose - Hi, the examples above are just from a regular expression helper I came across on the web ([RegExr](http://regexr.com?36e01)). My actual text entry would be coming from a simple text input rendered from the view in an ASP.NET MVC application. I was just playing around with different possible input values on the regex site. My bad for not making my question clearer. After a little more tinkering on the site I came to the same conclusion as Dukeling's answer below. I will edit my question though to make this clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of line indicators:

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

Some language also have functions that allows you to match against an entire string, where-as you were using a `find` function. Matching against the entire string will make your regex work as an alternative to the above. The above regex will also work, but the `^` and `$` will be redundant.

Comment: Depending on the programing language you need to switch the operation mode of the ^$. (In PHP there are `singleline` and `multiline` modes: `singleline` will force `^` to match the START of the string, and `$` to match the end. `multiline` will also accept linebreaks for the `$` - which is what you want.)

Comment: @dognose You might be right, but "I would like to use regex to match a **string** of exactly 2 characters".

Comment: Yes, but therefore your regex will fail, because the desired `12` is in the thirdline. (he wants to extract every LINE that has exactly 2 digits) - only one match in the given example.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use anchors to match the beginning of the string `^` and the end of the string `$`

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

Answer (score 14):

Something like this would work

```
/^\d{2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution, `[0-9]{2}`, matches when you always have two digits, even when representing a single-digit number, such as 01 for 1.

If you are dealing with plain numbers 'intgers' from 0 to 12, representing say a 12-hour clock, you can use the following expression:

```py
r"1[0-2]|[1-9]"
```

account for two-digit numbers between 10 and 12 as well as single-digit numbers from 1 to 9

Here's the breakdown:

- `1[0-2]`: Matches numbers 10, 11, and 12.
- `|[1-9]`: The `|` is an alternation operator, meaning "or." This part matches single-digit numbers from 1 to 9.