# Grep a 1 or 2 character number from a variable in R

Tags: r

I have two tables, `Grow` and `Temp`. `Grow` details the growing and nongrowing seasons for each area I'm concerned with (these are static), while `Temp` details the average temperature each month of a wide range of years (these are columns) for those same areas. I'm trying to identify the average temperature each year for the growing and nongrowing seasons, but I've run into a problem with how I pick the columns - I'm using `grep`, but can't figure out how to account for two-digit months!

At this point I've isolated each column of years, and have a vector of column names for a single year - something like `"tmp_2001_1" "tmp_2001_2" "tmp_2001_3" ... "tmp_2001_11" "tmp_2001_12"`. I also have, stored in a pair of variables, the start and end of growing season, which are stored as integers representing months: `start <- some number between 1 and 12`, `end <- some number between 1 and 12`. But I can't figure out how to get `grep` to identify the growing season when `start` or `end` has 2 digits. This is what I have that works for the case of them both being 1 digit numbers:

```
grow_months <- grep(paste('tmp_','2001','_','[',start,'-',end,']',sep = ''), vector_of_column_names)
```

How can I expand this to account for cases where `start` or `end` is double digit?

Comment: Don't try to do this all in one line. Use one line to extract the month number (you could use `gsub` or `stringr::str_extract`) and convert to numeric, and a second line to do the comparison with your start and end.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922660/regex-to-match-a-2-digit-number

Comment: I'll try that! It makes more sense to do it in two lines. And @js86, how can I use that to identify a range with distinct start and stop points?

Answer (score 1):

As Gregor suggests,

```
strings = paste0("tmp_2001_",c(1:20,100))
start = 9
end = 12
ii = sapply(strsplit(strings,'_'), function(x)x[3]%in%start:end)
strings[ii]
```

or using an easy regex you could try

```
ii = grep(paste(paste0('_(',start:end,')$'),collapse='|'), strings)
strings[ii]
```